# Will create and destroy Azure Windows 2019 Server cost more than shutting it down?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Currently I am working on test automation, I am considering two options now in term of saving cost for Azure VM. The test automation runs daily.

1. Host the virtual machine and shut it down when the automation process completed
2. Destroy the virtual machine when automation process completed and create the virtual machine again the next day.

I need some expert view on this, which option will save the cost more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option 2 will save more money if you will delete the virtual disk as well. if you are not going to delete the virtual disk (so your vm creation process is not 100% automated) its easier to deallocate it (it will still cost you money if its just stopped, not deallocated). And strictly from the perspective of billing deallocated or deleted VM both cost nothing.

But you cannot stop a virtual disk, only delete it.